# results.php shows all old queries

Tags: php, mysql

I created a website search bar using php with mysql, my results page shows all old queries. I even tried from other computers and search queries still appear. I do not have duplicate keywords so that should not be an issue. How can I get the results page to dump old queries?

```
<?php
        $input = $_GET['input'];//Note to self $input in the name of the search feild
        $terms = explode(" ", $input);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

        foreach ($terms as $each){
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1)
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            else
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        }

        // connecting to our mysql database
        mysql_connect("localhost", "pti_user", "policetech1");
        mysql_select_db("pti_db");

        $query = mysql_query($query);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0){

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
                $description<br /><br />";

            }

        }

        else

            echo "No results found for \"<b>$input</b>\"";

        // disconnect
        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: did you make the question clearly ? what's the result you wanted ?

Comment: What are old queries?

Comment: Lets say I search for "Contact", the results page shows "Contact Us". Then I search for "Product", the results page shows "Contact Us" and "Product" even though the keywords are not the same for each. This goes on and on. Each new query shows up under the previous queries. I just want the results page to clear out when the page is closed or a link on that page is clicked.

Comment: hello can you show search form code?

Comment: Above is the code from the results.php page and below is the code from my search.            `<form action="./results.php" method="get">
              <input type="text" value="Search..." name="keyword" id="keyword" title="keyword"
               onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" class="txt_field" />
              <input type="submit" name="Search" value='<?php echo $_GET['input']; ?>' alt="Search" id="searchbutton" title="Search" class="sub_btn"  />
            </form>`

Comment: Try to change method from "get" to "post" to understand where is problem because $_GET using parameters from url not only from form.

Comment: Made that change and no difference. I removed all .php files from the server, went through each page and re-uploaded them. Results page still shows old queries, so I am thinking that it is possibly a mysql issue.

Comment: I figured out that my issue was with the search form coding. I changed the code to  `<form action='results.php' method='get'>
   <input type='text' name='input' class="sarch-field" /> 
   <input type='submit' value='Search' class="seach-button">
  </form>` and the problem resolved itself.